# Screencast Recording extension for chrome using chrome native client

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I am new to chrome extension development.
I am trying to make an extension for recording screens and audio.

I searched a lot, and looked into some existing extensions like "MediaCore Capture" and "ScreenCastify". It seems they are using some NaCl (Native Client libraries).

I tried debugging but I am not sure what exactly flow they are using..

Then I came across a github repository "https://github.com/aaerox/inspire/" There I found some same sort of code..

I found some nexe and pnexe files also...

On more debugging "MediaCore Capture" code, I found it is also using some nexe.. which I now understand is some compiled native code...

Can anyone help how these can used ?
Or is there anything else that I can use for my extension..

I tried using ffmpeg_asm but it was very slow in merging audio and video streams.. so I am looking into some faster solution.

Comment: Did you manage to get any result, I want to build something similar? I can not find useful resources